# JSOUP - how to get content of Facebook event page as logged in user?

Tags: java, facebook, cookies, jsoup

When you are logged into Facebook, content of page is little different, like:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/host" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard  /page.php?id=someID" data-hovercard-position="below">One of event hosts</a>
```

instead of just:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/host">One of hosts</a>
```

I've tried a few ways to take page content with hovercard. I really don't have any more idea how to do that, my last try was:

```
        String login = "secret.user@gmail.com";
        String password = "veryHardPassword";
        String URL = "https://www.facebook.com/events/";
        String loginURL = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
        String useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0";
        String referrer = "http://www.google.com";

        Connection.Response res2 = Jsoup.connect(loginURL)
                .userAgent(useragent)
                .referrer(referrer)
                .data("email", login,"pass", password)
                .method(Method.POST).execute();

        Map<String, String> cookies = res2.cookies();
        Response res = Jsoup.connect(URL + "eventID")
                            .userAgent(useragent)
                            .referrer(referrer)
                            .timeout(200000)
                            .cookies(cookies)
                            .method(Method.POST)
                            .execute();

        Document doc = res.parse();
        System.out.print(doc);
```

Unfortunately that cookies are changing during logging in. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Why not use the Facebook API instead of scraping data?

Comment: Because it returns only host that created event, not all of them ;/

Comment: Could it be the simple answer that Facebook uses JavaScript to render it's content, which JSoup cannot execute, thus you are getting a different result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally make it, this code is working if someone would need this:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(URLEvent + eventFBId);
final HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(45000);

final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
textField.setValueAttribute(login);
final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("pass");
textField2.setValueAttribute(password);
page1 = (HtmlPage) form.getInputByValue("Log In").click();

URL url = new URL(URLEvent + eventFBId);
Set<Cookie> set = webClient.getCookies(url);

Map<String, String> mapFromSet = new HashMap<String, String>();
   for (Cookie entry : set) {
       mapFromSet.put(entry.getName(), entry.getValue());
   }

Map<String, String> cookies = mapFromSet;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cookies.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
    }

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URLEvent + eventFBId)
                    .userAgent(useragent)
                    .timeout(200000)
                    .data("email", login)           
                    .data("pass", password)
                    .cookies(cookies).get();

System.out.println(doc);
```